# Can Django ModelAdmin display foreign key fields in the "add" and "change" pages?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.9 to design a database website, and in my models, I have a 'franchise' table and a 'items' table.

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models


class franchise(models.Model):
    """Parent to all entires in item db"""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class item(models.Model):
    """Core database containing all entries in db"""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    franchise = models.ForeignKey(franchise, on_delete=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
```

As you can see, 'item' has a foreign key to 'franchise'

My admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from db.models import *


# Displaying the franchise database
class FranchiseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)

admin.site.register(franchise, FranchiseAdmin)


# Displaying the core database
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Get name of parent franchise
    def get_franchise(self, obj):
        return obj.franchise.name
    # Columns to display
    list_display = ('title', 'get_franchise', 'description')

admin.site.register(item, ItemAdmin)
```

The function 'get_franchise' is so I can display the value of 'name' from the foreign key table on the list page. I want the achieve the same functionality in the entry add and change pages in Django admin.

How do I display foreign key values in the 'add' and 'change' pages, so I can see the 'name' of the parent franchise when I add and change rows in the item table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to add `__str__` method (or `__unicode__` for python 2) to your models. There's no need to create special methods to just display values of `ForeignKey`s.

```
class franchise(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for py2
        return self.name

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'franchise', 'description')
```

Comment: How can we change the title of the field?. This worked, but the title of the field still displays the name of the primary key.

Comment: Then you will have to create custom method like @99lives did and set `short_description` for it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-change-list for details of admin customization.